# How can I get table tuple and transform it into an array in C for postgres?

Tags: c, postgresql, algorithm, hierarchical-clustering

I'm following Postgres documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/xfunc-c.html for writing C function and creating the extension (for hierarchial clustering) and I'm confused.

1. So I can get a tuple by using `HeapTupleHeader t = PG_GETARG_HEAPTUPLEHEADER(0);`
2. How can I get attribute values in this tuple? We have `GET_ARGUMENT_BY_NUM`, can I get a value for each column and put it into an array? (For some reason i want to get data from table and for example, clusterize it).
3. There is an example of using specific table for a function (emp table). How can I use random table for my function (I couldn't find the example)?
4. Is `c_overpaid(emp, limit)` (in documentation) called one time for emp table, or is it called as much as the rows in the table?
5. for hierarchical-clustering: can I get table data from postgres, write it into a temp file, read that file, put it into array, clusterize it and put the result into database? (like create or alter table and do a partitioning? like this: hub - is whole table, part_1 is one cluster, part_2 is the second one etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read [the documentation for the current version](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-c.html).

1. Yes.
2. As the example shows, with `GetAttributeByName`, but there is also a `GetAttributeByNum` function. I assume you are talking about a C array and not a PostgreSQL array. You can stuff all the values into an array, sure, if they have the same data type.
3. Then you would have to use the special type `record`. For a code sample, look at the functions `record_to_json` and `composite_to_json` in `src/backend/utils/adt/json.c`.
4. It is called for each row found, since it appears in the `SELECT` list.
5. That's a bit vague, but sure. I don't see why you'd want to extract that from a table though. Why not write your own *table access method*, since it looks like you want to define a new way of storing tables.

   But be warned, that would be decidedly non-trivial, and you'd better first get your feet wet with more mundane stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the code example! Still have questions about the sequence: so, i have a function row_to_json: i get there a row of a table, then call composite_to_json and get row values? and there i get confused - what's happening in the datum_to_json? Is that datum - value in the row's column and we're writing the value in json?

Comment: `datum_to_json` is a helper function that converts a value of a different type to `json`, mostly by calling the type output function. I don't think it is of value for your case.

Comment: okay, thank you for your answer and the last question: is there any way to debug my c function?

Comment: Sure, any C debugger will do. But you cannot run the function outside PostgreSQL.

Comment: Can I debug my function inside PostgreSQL though?

Comment: Sure. Attach with gdb.